# How to mock http connectors in munit

Tags: mule

We are having our custom http connector and an outbound which refers to that connector as follows

```
<http:connector name="myConnector">
<!-- config -->
</http:connector>
<http:endpoint name="myEndpoint" ref="myConnector">
<!-- config -->
</http:endpoint>

<http:outbound-endpoint name="myOutbound" ref="myEndpoint">
```

When I am mocking http outbound without specifying any attributes then its mocking .But if I am using mock while specifying attributes then it is throwing exception saying

```
"cannot process event as myConnector has stopped working".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default munit will stop the connector, and if you're seeing that message it means your not hitting the correct mocked endpoint. I would check that the attributes correctly match. Can you post your mock configuration and your endpoint configuration? So a better answer can be provided.

You can mock endpoints the same was as any message processor:

```
whenMessageProcessor("outbound-endpoint").ofNamespace("http").thenReturnSameEvent()
```

As a side note if you don't want the connector to be stopped by default you can override haveToMockMuleConnectors from FunctionalMunitSuite:

```
@Override
    public boolean haveToMockMuleConnectors() {
        return false;
    }
```

But then you won't hit the mocked endpoint.